# How can I recover my data after replacing ubuntu with windows 7?

Tags: lubuntu, windows-7, data-recovery

Recently, a technician installed windows 7 over already installed ubuntu in my 32-bit computer, and i have lost most important data, how to recover my data? please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

#### Whatever you do, DO NOT continue using your computer! The more you use it, the smaller  the chance of recovery will be!

---

Since Windows 7 was installed over Ubuntu, your partition table is history.

My recommended course of action would be to use `dd` to image your internal drive to an external one, and then attempt recovery from the external drive. That way, if you screw anything up, you can always re-image from the original.

Once you've done that, how to proceed will depend on how severe the damage is. Luckily, EXT4 doesn't just store an MFT at the beginning and end of the partition as NTFS does, so you have a *chance* of getting *some* stuff back, although **there will definitely be some files that are completely history since they were overwritten**.

---

### After you've imaged your drive, give this a read:

**https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery**

Comment: okk, thanks for giving me solution, i am going to try it. For more information, Is there any free software available for my intended task?

Comment: There are some softwares i googled them, easeus, irecovery etc. , can anyone of these is useful to me?

Comment: @jane You need a software that can recovery from EXT4

Comment: Good answer although I don't understand why you mentioned the partition table at the beginning. That is not really the problem, the issue is that parts of the file system have been overwritten.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto well if the partition table is gone that can make recovery more difficult since the software doesn't know where to look, and so it has to scan the entire drive.

Comment: @AndroidDev it takes two minutes to recover a partition table with TestDisk. It takes a considerably higher amount of time to extract something if the file system inside the partition has been damaged.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I have limited experience with recovering data - I just make frequent backups so it isn't really an issue for me - sounds like you have more experience with this and should write your own answer :)

Comment: @AndroidDev “ I just make frequent backups” This means you are wise and a lot more experienced than you think. :P Unfortunately I have more insights on the opposite situation (i.e. recovering Windows / NTFS after damages). Your answer is good, I just spotted the reference to the partition table that seemed a bit extraneous.